# MongoMapper to Mongoid: How to search inside an array?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, mongomapper

"self" here stands for Contact model.
This query will find all completed tasks for a contact.
The Task model has a field/key :assigned_contacts of type Array.
So the query is searching inside    the Array.

```
def assigned_tasks_completed
  self.company.tasks.all(:assigned_contacts => self.id.to_s, :completed => true)
end
```

How to do this in Mongoid?

Another question:
The equivalent in Mongoid of @contact.set(:a -> a, :b -> b, :c -> c) is update_attributes!

But there is also a method set in Mongoid.
What is the difference between set & update_attributes! in Mongoid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your tasks is a separate document. So you can just replace `all` with `where`, it will work

```
def assigned_tasks_completed
  self.company.tasks.where(:assigned_contacts => self.id.to_s, :completed => true)
end
```

For your another question,

Both mongoid [set](http://mongoid.org/docs/persistence/atomic.html#set) & [update attributes](http://mongoid.org/docs/persistence/standard.html#update_attributes) are internally uses [mongodb $set](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24set). But the difference is mongoid set is only accepts single field update, update_attributes accepts multiple.